# How to use edited lattice?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, geometry-nodes, lattice

is there any way to bind an object to an edited lattice ? the way that the geometry at first don't changes , instead it takes changes after binding ? Something like mesh deform but with lattice ...

Comment: lattice doesn't work like mesh deform, if you edit the lattice in Edit mode it will deform the object right away

Comment: @moonboots thanks , lets see if anyone knows any workaround

Answer (score 2):

You can fake this using the strength parameter of the Lattice modifier:

[image: Lattice modifier showing strength set to 0]

Here's a cube inside the lattice with the Strength set to 0

[image: cube not deforming]

Strength set to .5

[image: cube partially deformed by lattice]

This will help you if you're trying to use the lattice in an animation, or just to leave the object alone while you're working on the lattice.